# Display two box inline

Tags: html, css

I want to display two boxes `inline`. I tried a lot to solve it.

```css
.checks {
    width:100%;
}
.moinfo {
    background:#F29400;
    width:50%;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    margin-top:30px;
    color: white !important;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    height:300px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.role {
    background:green;
    width:50%;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    margin-top:30px;
    color: white !important;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    height:300px;
}
.hmovie {
    border-bottom:3px dotted #93117E;
    color:white;
    width:200px;
}
.cat {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    padding-bottom:3px;
    border-bottom:2px dotted white;
}
.cat {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    padding-bottom:3px;
}
.subcat {
    float:left;
    width:40%;
}
.dcont {
    float:left;
    width:60%;
}
```

```html
<div class='checks'>
    <div class='moinfo'>
         <h2 class='hmovie'>Movie Information</h2>

        <div class='cat'>
            <div class='subcat'>Genre:</div>
            <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[0]."</div>
        </div>
        <div class='cat'>
            <div class='subcat'>Year:</div>
            <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[1]."</div>
        </div>
        <div class='cat'>
            <div class='subcat'>Running Time:</div>
            <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[2]."</div>
        </div>
        <div class='cat'>
            <div class='subcat'>Language:</div>
            <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[3]."</div>
        </div>
        <div class='cat'>
            <div class='subcat'>Subtitles:</div>
            <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[4]."</div>
        </div>
        <div class='cat'>
            <div class='subcat'>Country:</div>
            <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[5]."</div>
        </div>
        <div class='lcat'>
            <div class='subcat'>Awards:</div>
            <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[6]."</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='role'>
         <h2 class='hmovie'>Cast Information</h2>

        <div class='cat'>
            <div class='subcat'>Cast:</div>
            <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[7]."</div>
        </div>
        <div class='cat'>
            <div class='subcat'>Director:</div>
            <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[8]."</div>
        </div>
        <div class='cat'>
            <div class='subcat'>Writer:</div>
            <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[9]."</div>
        </div>
        <div class='cat'>
            <div class='subcat'>Producers:</div>
            <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[10]."</div>
        </div>
        <div class='cat'>
            <div class='subcat'>Music:</div>
            <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[11]."</div>
        </div>
        <div class='cat'>
            <div class='subcat'>Cinematography:</div>
            <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[12]."</div>
        </div>
        <div class='lcat'>
            <div class='subcat'>Editor:</div>
            <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[13]."</div>
        </div>
        <div class='lcat'>
            <div class='subcat'>Sound:</div>
            <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[13]."</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7jeye9y6/1/#&togetherjs=xIgcyw0OUr)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: use float:left in both classes CSS and if you worte clear:both... remove that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `display:inline-flex` to your `.checks`.

```css
.checks {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
}
.moinfo {
  background: #F29400;
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: white !important;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.role {
  background: green;
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: white !important;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  height: 300px;
}
.hmovie {
  border-bottom: 3px dotted #93117E;
  color: white;
  width: 200px;
}
.cat {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted white;
}
.cat {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.subcat {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
}
.dcont {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class='checks'>
  <div class='moinfo'>
    <h2 class='hmovie'>Movie Information</h2>
    <div class='cat'>
      <div class='subcat'>Genre:</div>
      <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[0]."</div>
    </div>
    <div class='cat'>
      <div class='subcat'>Year:</div>
      <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[1]."</div>
    </div>
    <div class='cat'>
      <div class='subcat'>Running Time:</div>
      <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[2]."</div>
    </div>
    <div class='cat'>
      <div class='subcat'>Language:</div>
      <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[3]."</div>
    </div>
    <div class='cat'>
      <div class='subcat'>Subtitles:</div>
      <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[4]."</div>
    </div>
    <div class='cat'>
      <div class='subcat'>Country:</div>
      <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[5]."</div>
    </div>
    <div class='lcat'>
      <div class='subcat'>Awards:</div>
      <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[6]."</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='role'>
    <h2 class='hmovie'>Cast Information</h2>
    <div class='cat'>
      <div class='subcat'>Cast:</div>
      <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[7]."</div>
    </div>
    <div class='cat'>
      <div class='subcat'>Director:</div>
      <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[8]."</div>
    </div>
    <div class='cat'>
      <div class='subcat'>Writer:</div>
      <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[9]."</div>
    </div>
    <div class='cat'>
      <div class='subcat'>Producers:</div>
      <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[10]."</div>
    </div>
    <div class='cat'>
      <div class='subcat'>Music:</div>
      <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[11]."</div>
    </div>
    <div class='cat'>
      <div class='subcat'>Cinematography:</div>
      <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[12]."</div>
    </div>
    <div class='lcat'>
      <div class='subcat'>Editor:</div>
      <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[13]."</div>
    </div>
    <div class='lcat'>
      <div class='subcat'>Sound:</div>
      <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[13]."</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It was working perfectly fine in Firefox. I have not tested in Chrome. Then @Twix should look for other answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have applied `padding`, the *effective* total width of both `<div>`'s with width `50%` will be more than `100%`. You can Apply `box-sizing:border-box` for both the `<div>`s to include the padding while calculating the `width` and `height`.

Still, `inline-block` elements will respect the linebreaks in your `HTML` which will be converted to a white space, Breaking your `100%` total again. You can either try fixing it using [these hackish methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements), Or you can simply float them  `left` and `right` respectively instead.

```css
.checks {
    width:100%;
}
.moinfo {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    float:left;
    background:#F29400;
    width:50%;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    margin-top:30px;
    color: white !important;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    height:300px;
}
.role {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    float:right;
    background:green;
    width:50%;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    margin-top:30px;
    color: white !important;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    height:300px;
}
.hmovie {
    border-bottom:3px dotted #93117E;
    color:white;
    width:200px;
}
.cat {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    padding-bottom:3px;
    border-bottom:2px dotted white;
}
.cat {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    padding-bottom:3px;
}
.subcat {
    float:left;
    width:40%;
}
.dcont {
    float:left;
    width:60%;
}
```

```html
<div class='checks'>
    <div class='moinfo'>
        <h2 class='hmovie'>Movie Information</h2>
        <div class='cat'>
            <div class='subcat'>Genre:</div>
            <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[0]."</div>
        </div>
        <div class='cat'>
            <div class='subcat'>Year:</div>
            <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[1]."</div>
        </div>
        <div class='cat'>
            <div class='subcat'>Running Time:</div>
            <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[2]."</div>
        </div>
        <div class='cat'>
            <div class='subcat'>Language:</div>
            <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[3]."</div>
        </div>
        <div class='cat'>
            <div class='subcat'>Subtitles:</div>
            <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[4]."</div>
        </div>
        <div class='cat'>
            <div class='subcat'>Country:</div>
            <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[5]."</div>
        </div>
        <div class='lcat'>
            <div class='subcat'>Awards:</div>
            <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[6]."</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='role'>
        <h2 class='hmovie'>Cast Information</h2>
        <div class='cat'>
            <div class='subcat'>Cast:</div>
            <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[7]."</div>
        </div>
        <div class='cat'>
            <div class='subcat'>Director:</div>
            <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[8]."</div>
        </div>
        <div class='cat'>
            <div class='subcat'>Writer:</div>
            <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[9]."</div>
        </div>
        <div class='cat'>
            <div class='subcat'>Producers:</div>
            <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[10]."</div>
        </div>
        <div class='cat'>
            <div class='subcat'>Music:</div>
            <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[11]."</div>
        </div>
        <div class='cat'>
            <div class='subcat'>Cinematography:</div>
            <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[12]."</div>
        </div>
        <div class='lcat'>
            <div class='subcat'>Editor:</div>
            <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[13]."</div>
        </div>
        <div class='lcat'>
            <div class='subcat'>Sound:</div>
            <div class='dcont'>".$dummy[13]."</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to do this:

1. You need to add "`display:inline-block`" to the second element + "`box-sizing: border-box;`" to both elements in order to include the padding in the "50%" width.

Your code should look like this:

```
.moreinfo{ 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
    display:inline-block;
    width:50%;
}
```

2. Remove the `display` property and add "`float:left`" (this will actually change the display to `block`);
   Add "`overflow:hidden`" to the parent.
   http://jsfiddle.net/7jeye9y6/7/

Answer (score 0):

you need to add
`display:inline-block` 
to second box, and change width of boxes

http://jsfiddle.net/7jeye9y6/2

Comment: The `<div>`s in actual demo have `50%` width each, not `45%`.

Comment: as i wrote "and change width of boxes"

Answer (score 0):

Just add display inline flex to you .checks class and -webkit-inline-flex if safari

```
.checks{ 
    width:100%;
    display:inline-flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `display:inline-block` for both the div. Also use `box-sizing:border-box` to calculate excess padding. Update your CSS like below.

```
 .moinfo{ 
    background:#F29400;
    width:50%;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    margin-top:30px;
    color: white !important ;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    height:300px;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    box-sizing:border-box;    
 }

.role{ 
    background:green;
    width:50%;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    margin-top:30px;
    color: white !important ;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    height:300px;
    font-size: 14px;
    display:inline-block;
    box-sizing:border-box;
  }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7jeye9y6/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You are using 50% 50% and placing paddings left and right of 10px; this makes it more than 100%; also, either you choose float:left;  or display:inline;

This Made them displayed inline:

```
        .moinfo{ 
            background:#F29400;
            width:46%;
            margin:0px;
            padding-left:2%;
            padding-right:2%;
            margin-top:30px;
            color: white !important ;
            padding-bottom:20px;
            height:300px;
            display:inline-block;
            float:left;

        }

        .role{ 
        margin:0px;
            background:green;
            width:46%;
            padding-left:2%;
            padding-right:2%;
            margin-top:30px;
            color: white !important ;
            padding-bottom:20px;
            height:300px;
            float:left;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your `.moinfo` and `.role`

```
display:inline-block;
box-sizing:border-box;
```